# Creating an ArrayList of Employees

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, arraylist

I have three classes

- employee
- production workers
- shift supervisor class

My idea is to make production and shift supervisor extend the employee class and then create another class, `EmployeeList` to fill it with information about production workers and shift supervisors.

How can i get the names and info from employee class to iterate into an arraylist?

How can i add a random list of employees more than half being prod. workers and the rest shift supervisors?

Employee:

```
public class Employee {

public String EmployeeName;
public String EmployeeNumber;
public int hireyear;
public double WeeklyEarning;

public Employee()
{
    EmployeeName = null;
    EmployeeNumber = null;
    hireyear = 0;
    WeeklyEarning = 0;

}

public static final String[] Enum = new String[] {
        "0001-A", "0002-B","0003-C","0004-D","0002-A",
        "0003-B","0004-C","0005-D","0011-A", "0012-B",
        "0013-C","0014-D","0121-A", "0122-B","0123-C" };

public static final String[] Ename = new String[] {
        "Josh", "Alex", "Paul", "Jimmy", "Josh", "Gordan", "Neil", "Bob",
        "Shiv", "James", "Jay", "Chris", "Michael", "Andrew", "Stuart"};

public String getEmployeeName()
{
    return this.EmployeeName;
}

public String getEmployeeNumber()
{
    return this.EmployeeNumber;
}

public int gethireyear()
{
    return this.hireyear;
}

public double getWeeklyEarning()
{
    return this.WeeklyEarning;
}

public String setEmployeeName(String EName)
{
    return this.EmployeeName = EName;
}

public String setEmployeeNumber(String ENumber)
{
    return this.EmployeeNumber = ENumber;
}

public int setEmployeehireyear(int Ehireyear)
{
    return this.hireyear = Ehireyear;
}

public double setEmployeeweeklyearning(double Eweeklyearning)
{
    return this.WeeklyEarning = Eweeklyearning;
}

}
```

ProductionWorker:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class ProductionWorker extends Employee {
public double HourlyRate;
public ProductionWorker()
{
    super();
    HourlyRate = 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProductionWorker pw = new ProductionWorker();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int count =0;
    // adding random Employees.....
    while(count<5)
    {
        int num= rnd.nextInt(Enum.length);
        int decimal = rnd.nextInt(10);
        double dec = decimal/10;

        pw.setEmployeeName(Ename[num]);
        pw.setEmployeeNumber(Enum[num]);
        pw.setEmployeehireyear(rnd.nextInt(35) + 1980);
        pw.setEmployeeweeklyearning(rnd.nextInt(5000) + 5000);
        pw.setHourlyRate(rnd.nextInt(44) + 6 + dec);

        System.out.println("EmployeeName: " + pw.getEmployeeName() + "\nEmployeeNumber: " + pw.getEmployeeNumber() +
            "\nHireYear: " + pw.gethireyear() + "\nWeeklyEarning: " +     pw.getWeeklyEarning() +
            "\nHourlyRate: " + pw.getHourlyRate() +"\n");
        count++;
    }

}

public double getHourlyRate()
{
    return this.HourlyRate;
}

public void setHourlyRate(double hourlyrate)
{
    this.HourlyRate = hourlyrate;
}

}
```

ShiftSupervisor:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class ShiftSupervisor extends Employee{
public double YearlySalary;
public int GoalsCleared;

public ShiftSupervisor()
{
    super();
    YearlySalary = 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ShiftSupervisor S = new ShiftSupervisor();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int count =0;
    // adding random Employees.....
    System.out.println("Adding Employees..");
    while(count<5)
    {
        int num= rnd.nextInt(Enum.length);          

        S.setEmployeeName(Ename[num]);
        S.setEmployeeNumber(Enum[num]);
        S.setEmployeehireyear(rnd.nextInt(35) + 1980);
        S.setEmployeeweeklyearning(rnd.nextInt(100) * 100);
        S.setYearlySalary(rnd.nextInt(40000) + 40000);

        System.out.println("EmployeeName:" + S.getEmployeeName() + "\nEmployeeNumber: " + S.getEmployeeNumber() +
            "\nHireYear: " + S.gethireyear() + "\nWeeklyEarning: " + S.getWeeklyEarning() +
            "\nearlySalary: " + S.getYearlySalary() +"\n");
        count++;
    }

}
// returns yearly salary
public double getYearlySalary()
{
    return this.YearlySalary;
}

// returns goals cleared
public int getGoalsCleared()
{
    return this.GoalsCleared;
}

// set yearly salary
public void setYearlySalary(double yearlysalary)
{
    this.YearlySalary = yearlysalary;
}

}
```

Comment: I clarified your introductory statement, moved your second question from top to bottom.  I also edited your title to better reflect your question. You should definitely try and remove some code from your samples, it is a bit too much to be appealing to debug, as well as clarify what your two questions are (try and keep it short)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do is have all necessary fields set in the constructor. If an `Employee` doesn't "exist" until it has a name, then that should be part of the constructor.

Then, I would suggest you consider renaming some of your fields. When I first saw `Enum` as a `String[]` and highlighted as a type, it took me a moment to figure out what exactly was going on. Renaming it to `employeeNumbers` could solve this.

Next, I think you should have an `EmployeeGenerator` class whose sole purpose is generating `Employee`s.

```
public class EmployeeGenerator {

    public ProductionWorker generateProductionWorker() {
        Random rng = new Random();
        int numberOfEmployeeNames = employeeNames.length;
        String employeeName = employeeNames[rng.nextInt(numberOfEmployeeNames)];
        int numberOfEmployeeNumbers = employeeNumbers.length;
        String employeeNumber = employeeNumbers[rng.nextInt(numberOfEmployeeNumbers)];
        ProductionWorker worker = new ProductionWorker(employeeName, employeeNumber);

        int yearHired = rng.nextInt(100) + 1900;
        worker.setHireYear(yearHired);

        int hourlyRate = rng.nextInt(20) + 10;
        worker.setHourlyRate(hourlyRate);

        // any other fields...
        return worker;
    }

    // method to generate shift supervisor
}
```

And then you can simply do

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rng = new Random();
    int numberOfEmployeesToGenerate = 1000;
    int minimumNumberOfProductionWorkers = numberOfEmployeesToGenerate / 2;

    int numberOfProductionWorkersToGenerate = 
        minimumNumberOfProductionWorkers + rng.nextInt(100);

    int numberOfSupervisorsToGenerator =
        numberOfEmployeesToGenerate - numberOfProductionWorkersToGenerate;

    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    EmployeeGenerator generator = new EmployeeGenerator();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProductionWorkersToGenerate; i++) {
        ProductionWorker worker = generator.generateProductionWorker();
        employees.add(worker);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSupervisorsToGenerate; i++) {
        Supervisor supervisor = generator.generateSupervisor();
        employees.add(supervisor);
    }
}
```

This should hopefully give you a point in the right direction. This isn't perfect code, and there are other ways to refactor this to make it more maintainable and performant.

Comment: this was exactly what i needed, thanks for understanding where i was coming from

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want to add a random list of employees, What do you mean exactly?

Currently you instantiate only one `ProductionWorker` and one `ShiftSupervisor`, change the values of the member variables, and print some text to `StdOut`.

Do you want to store instances in a list or is the console output sufficient?

Also, you have two `main`-methods. Which one will be performed? It might be better to have one `Main` class as an entry point for your application and from there create the instances.

In general you can do something like that:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> emps = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            //create new employee
            emps.add(newEmployee);
        }
        //do something with list
    }
}
```